# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint, react-hooks

I am having this problem to build my app. Anyone knows what is wrong?

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'conectar'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

```
const GraficoEquivalenteNovo = props => {
  const [equivalenteNovos, setEquivalenteNovos] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  async function conectar() {
    const resposta = await ConexaoGraficoEquivalenteNovo(props);
    setEquivalenteNovos(resposta[0]);
    setData(resposta[1]);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    conectar();
  }, [props]);

  return (....)
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hook depends on the function `connectar` which is declared outside the hook, but is internal to the render process. It is re-manufactured on every render. Therefore, React sees it as a volatile dependency. You could have the function outside your component but since the function itself uses state hooks and depends on props, move it into the effect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
   async function conectar() { 
    const resposta = await ConexaoGraficoEquivalenteNovo(props); 
    setEquivalenteNovos(resposta[0]);
    setData(resposta[1]);
  } 

  conectar();
}, [props]);
```

Comment: The first scenario would be a pointless exercise given `conectar` is created on every render.

Comment: Yes, I'm about to remove it.

Comment: you have missing denpendency such as `setEquivalenteNovos`, `setData` and `ConexaoGraficoEquivalenteNovo`

Comment: @Vencovsky State hooks are not considered dependencies. `ConexaoGraficoEquivalenteNovo` is imported from outside the function component so it's not a dependency. It must be some other problem.

Comment: Maybe `ConexaoGraficoEquivalenteNovo` aren't a dependecy, but the other two are

Comment: They are state hooks created by React, so it's fine. Is this your code, are you having this problem?

Comment: Worked fine, tanks!