# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies (witout moving function inside useEffect)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

This is my part of code. Everything works fine but eslint gives error.

> React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'dispatch' and 'getData'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I found some solutions but all of say you need to move function inside the useEffect, but I can't. Because I'm calling setData() function sometimes that is in the Jsx.

So getData not only run when component mounted.

Some similar questions but as i said; I can't move function inside the useEffect. Answers always same:

[React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527984/react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency)

[React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938884/react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency-list)

```
export const Complex = (props) => {
// [+] Olmayan başlık tespiti. [+] Var olan başlık tespiti. [-] Daha önce
// açılmış fakat ilk entrysi silinmiş başlıklar.
const params = queryString.parse(props.location.search)

let id = props.location.pathname.split("--")[1];
let str = props.location.pathname.split("--")[0].substr(1);

const data = {
    id: id,
    link: str,
    page: params.sayfa ? parseInt(params.sayfa) : 1,
    isGood: params.guzel ? params.guzel : false
};


// STATE
const [title,setTitle] = useState("")
const [titleSubs,setTitleSubs] = useState("")
const [entryCount,setEntryCount] = useState()
const [titleId,setTitleID] = useState()
const [exist,setExist] = useState(true)
const [entries,setEntries] = useState([])
const [likes,setLikes] = useState([])
const [disabled,setDisable] = useState(false)
const [isLoading,setLoading] = useState(false)

// REDUX
const titleModal = useSelector(state => state.settings.titleModal)
const dataPage = useSelector(state => state.pageInfo.page)
const entryNormal = useSelector(state => state.character.entry.entryNormal)
const entryCats = useSelector(state => state.character.entryCats)
const isAuthenticated = useSelector(state => state.auth.authenticated)
const dispatch = useDispatch();

function getData() {
    setLoading(true)
    // For everyone
    axios.post('/api/data/entry/get', data)
    .then(res  => {
            setExist(true)
            setTitleID(res.data.title.id)
            setEntries(res.data.entries)
            setEntryCount(res.data.count)
            setTitle(res.data.title)
            setTitleSubs(res.data.title.titlesubs)
            setLoading(false)

            if (titleModal) {
                // Send Redux Link Informations
                dispatch(setCurrentPage({type: null, id: null, title: null}))
            } else {
                dispatch(setCurrentPage({type: "entry", id: res.data.title.id, title: res.data.title.title}))
            }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        setExist(false)
        setLoading(false)
        setTitle(str)
    })

    // If Authenticated.
    // Get liked entries.
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        axios.post('api/data/entry/likes/get', {titleId: data.id})
        .then(res => {
            const LikesList = [];
            res.data.forEach(data => {
                LikesList.push(data.EntryId)
            });
            setLikes(LikesList)
        })
    }

}

useEffect(() => {
    getData()
    return () => {
        setEntries([])
        dispatch(setCurrentPage({type: null, id: null, title: null}))
    }
}, [id, props.location.search])

function getGoodEntriesGeneral() {
    const params = queryString.parse(props.location.search)
    params['guzel'] = true;
    const serialize = obj => Object.keys(obj)
                         .map(key => `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[key])}`).join('&')
    history.push({
        pathname: props.location.pathname,
        search: serialize(params)
    })
}
```

Comment: Is `data` that you use inside `axios.post` comes from state?

Comment: @AsafAviv I updated question.

Answer (score 0):

A new version of settings for eslint provided by React creators enforce programmer to put all variables in the array. You can check https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-485912528